# Google Sheets - get the right-most / last non-empty value of a row from imported sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet which imports data from a different sheet.
I inserted the sheet ID of the imported sheet in cell A1 to make it easier for me.

I need something that I can give a ROW and it will always return the right most / last non-empty value. That is, it automatically updates whenever we add a column in the imported sheet.

I've found this formula to show the last value of row 9 of the same sheet:

```
=FILTER(9:9,COLUMN(9:9)=MAX(FILTER(COLUMN(9:9),LEN(9:9))))
```

But I'm struggling to show the last value of row 9 of the IMPORTED sheet. How can I connect this formula with the imported sheet, that means with the Sheet ID (inserted in my new sheet in cell A1)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Will there be blank columns in the rows? If not you could use count to identify the number of columns and indirect() to pull the value.

Answer (score 1):

Assumes the relevant row number is entered in A2. Ugly but might be good enough:

```
=index(indirect("Sheet!"&row(A2)&":"&row(A2)),MATCH(1E+100,indirect("Sheet!"&row(A2)&":"&row(A2),1)))
```

Replace `Sheet` as appropriate.